# ssh to amazon EC2 over proxy

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, proxy

I have some problem connecting to my amazon EC2 server over ssh over proxy.

I have my username and password for http proxy port 8080.(dont have control over proxy)
Also I have my connection string which would work without proxy
ssh -i key.pem root@xx.compute.amazonaws.com

1. when I am trying to connect I am getting "No route to host" error
2. I tried to use putty, configured proxy + authentication file, But then I getting this error
   "Unable to use this key file (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key)"
   Also I dont know how putty inserts my proxy config, into ssh connection string, so I could try it in terminal

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and this is what I used to connect, using corkscrew. My config file looks like this

```
Host AWS
    Hostname <Public DNS>
    Port 443
    #Write the appropriate username depending on your AMI, eg : ubuntu, ec2-user
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile </path to key file>
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 10.10.78.61 3128 %h %p
```

then I simply use this command to connect

`ssh AWS`

and it works flawlessly.

**Note** : You must edit your **sshd_config** file on the server to listen to ssh connections on port 443 (in addition to 22) and restart the ssh daemon.

Comment: I'm not sure how `Host AWS` works for you, unless you have it mapped in your `host` file. But if I put the <Public DNS> for the `host`, then this solution worked great.

Comment: @mattsnider I'm on Linux and this is how you alias your ssh configuration there, you could write it `Host YourFavName` and then do `ssh YourFavName` and it would still work. Not sure why it won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can login as root? Try logging in as `ec2-user` instead.

Also, if you have assigned an elastic IP to your instance, the public DNS has probably changed. Log in to the aws console, and select your instance. Scroll down to look at the public DNS again and double check you are using the correct xx.compute.amazonaws.com addr.

Comment: tried ec2-user, got the same problem. I am using correct DNS. Also after error "Unable to use this key file (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key)" I am getting pop up message "No supported authentication method available"

Comment: Note that each EC2 image (AMI) comes with its own convention for username. E.g., bitnami AMIs have the 'bitnami' user account into which you ssh